# ITextSharp not converting ordered lists correctly

Tags: c#, list, itext, pdf-generation, html-lists

I'm using `ITextSharp` to make `pdf` files and the problem is when I try to make `ITextSharp` convert my `html` text to `pdf`, it comes out wrong.

I want to know if it is possible to print the `ol` lists as they are and if so, how should I do it?

I'm using a `HTMLWorker` to parse the `html` string to a list,
then I iterate the list and I write the file in the file.

This is the code I am using:

```cs
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(txtConvertido))
{
    string txtreplace = txtConvertido;
    List<IElement> elements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, styles);
    foreach (IElement e in elements)
    {
        if (e is List)
        {
            List newlist = null;
            if (((List)e).Symbol.Content == "-")
            {
                newlist = new List(List.ORDERED);
                newlist.SetListSymbol("\u2022");
            }
            else if (((List)e).Symbol.Content == "• ")
            {
                newlist = new List(List.UNORDERED);
                newlist.SetListSymbol("•");
            }

            foreach (ListItem item in ((List)e).Items)
            {
                Chunk newchk = new Chunk(item.Chunks[0]);

                float fontsize = item.Chunks[0].Font.Size;
                if (fontsize == 1)
                    fontsize = font_Texto.Size;

                newchk.Font = new Font(font_Texto.BaseFont, fontsize, item.Chunks[0].Font.Style, item.Chunks[0].Font.Color);
                ListItem newitem = new ListItem() { Font = newchk.Font };
                newitem.Add(newchk);
                newlist.Add(newitem);
            }

            _p.Add(newlist);
        }
        else if (e is Paragraph)
        {
            foreach (Chunk chk in e.Chunks)
            {
                float fontsize = chk.Font.Size;
                if (fontsize == 1)
                    fontsize = font_Texto.Size;

                chk.Font = new Font(font_Texto.BaseFont, fontsize, chk.Font.Style, chk.Font.Color);
            }
            if (e is Paragraph)
            {
                if (((Paragraph)e).Alignment == -1)
                    ((Paragraph)e).Alignment = alinhamento;

                ((Paragraph)e).SetLeading(0, multipliedLeading);
            }
            _p.Add(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The part of the html file that doesn't convert correctly is the tag «ol start="x"»:

so, instead of printing:

```
1. ASDASD
2. gadsafasa
3. dsfa ggga
4. asdfa sdf
```

...

It prints as:

```
1. ASDASD
1. gadsafasa
1. dsfa ggga
1. asdfa sdf
```

...

Here Is the html:

```html
<ol>
    <li><strong>A «Nome Empresa»</strong></li>
</ol>
<br />
---[Descrever a atividade da empresa, o seu histórico, entre outras informações relevantes.]---<br />
<br />
&nbsp;

<ol start="2">
    <li><strong>&nbsp;O que é o código de ética e de conduta</strong></li>
</ol>
<br />
O Código de Ética e de Conduta
<br />
&nbsp;

<ol start="3">
    <li><strong>Aplicação</strong></li>
</ol>
<br />
O Código de Ética e de Conduta
<br />
&nbsp;

<ol start="4">
    <li><strong>Objetivos</strong></li>
</ol>
<br />
O Código de Ética e Conduta 
<br />
&nbsp;
<ol start="5">
    <li><strong>Acompanhamento</strong></li>
</ol>
<br />
Todos os colaboradores, clientes, parceiros e fornecedores
&nbsp;
```

Comment: Your example shows the same results when printing, may need to update your post.

Comment: in the text editor it was correct, but the preview was indeed wrong, thanks for pointing that out, I made them be inside a code block and now they show correctly.

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? Can you try with iText 7.1.6 + pdfHTML 2.1.3 and tell us if the problem still occurs?

Comment: @RyanWilson the values are the same but the enumeration is correct on one, and is wrong on the other (as in they all start with '1.')

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse the iText version we're using here is the 5.5.6.0 the pdfHTML I can't find, Unfortunately I can't updade the version in case its not compatible with the rest of the project, since it's a really big project.

Comment: It's on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7 and https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfhtml/. iText 5 is End Of Life, which means no more updates, except security fixes for customers.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Can you tell me if updating the iText version will have code implications, I can't deal with them right now since I'm on a tight schedule

Comment: @ErickSantander I would hope you have some kind of Version Control for your project, just branch it and add the new version of `itextsharp` and see if it breaks anything.

Comment: @RyanWilson in their website https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/itext-7-and-itext-5-roadmaps-differences-updates they say that it's not backwards compatible. so as it is right now I can't update it...

Comment: There will be code implications, in most cases you will need to write less code to do the same thing. And indeed not backwards compatible.

Comment: I know there will be code implications, it's just that I don't have enough time to apply them now.

Comment: @ErickSantander Perhaps some of what is discussed here will give you some ideas as to how to fix your problem (http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/HTML-to-PDF-XMLWorker-Ordered-Lists-td4113053.html)